# C: Passing argument into Program to convert characters into ASCII values

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, ascii

I am writing a program that takes a command line argument and user input, and calculates the difference between the two characters (cryptography). I would like to pass my argument into a variable within the program, but am unable to do so.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

char plain[2];
char cipher[2];   /*locations of plain and cipher text*/

char *ppoint; /*pointers to plain and cipher*/
char *cpoint;

scanf("%s",plain);
*ppoint=plain[0];     /* ppoint points to 1st character in plain*/

cipher=argv[1];  /* cpoint points to first argument character*/
*cpoint=cipher[1];

printf("%s %d \n",ppoint,plain);
printf("%s %d \n",cpoint,cipher);

return 0;



}
```

For line 14, I am met with a compiler error ,
(cipher=argv[1];) " Incompatible types in assignment "
I have been experimenting with many methods such as type casting but I can not get anything to work.

I would like the two last lines of my program to output the actual character and their respective ASCII values. Please help me past this block!

UPDATE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

char plain;
char *cipher;   /*locations of plain and cipher text*/

int *ppoint; /*pointers to plain and cipher*/
int *cpoint;

scanf("%s",plain);
*ppoint=(int) plain;     /* ppoint points to 1st character in plain*/

cipher=argv[1];  /* cpoint points to first argument character*/
*cpoint=(int) cipher;

printf("%s %d \n",plain);
printf("%s %d \n",cipher);

return 0;

    }
```

I used type casting to fix any compiler errors. However upon running the program and in putting a value for 'plain', I am met with a segmentation fault. I have looked long and hard but cannot see where this memory error is occurring. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to assign a `char` pointer to a `char` array, which is not allowed.  You'll need to copy the argument some other way.  For example, you could use strcpy:

```
strcpy(cipher,argv[1]);
```

Alternatively, you could make `cipher` be a `char` pointer instead if you never modify it.

```
const char *cipher;

...

cipher = argv[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

try using,

```
ppoint=(int) plain;     /* ppoint points to 1st character in plain*/
```

Without the '*', as you cannot use the de-referencing operator on the pointer variable as the pointer doesn't point to any location yet.